# Python access to Skin Modifier data - again

Tags: python, modifiers

I am trying to access skin modifier vertices data. An [older solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/blender-python-to-access-skin-modifier-radius-data) does not work in my Blender 2.75 / 2.76:

```
print('has skin=', bool(context.active_object.modifiers['Skin']))
data = context.active_object.data
print(data)
vert = data.skin_vertices
print('skin_vertices=', vert)
v0d = data.skin_vertices[0]
print('skin_vertices[0]=', v0d)
v0d_data = v0d.data
print('skin_vertices_data=', v0d_data)
print('--------loop--------')
for v in v0d_data:
    print('skin_vertex=', v)
```

That returns:

```
has skin= True  
bpy_struct, Mesh("Skin")  
skin_vertices= bpy_collection[1], Mesh.skin_vertices  
skin_vertices[0]= bpy_struct, MeshSkinVertexLayer("")  
skin_vertices_data= bpy_collection[4], MeshSkinVertexLayer.data  
--------loop--------
```

According to python api skin_vertices return `MeshSkinVertexLayer` not `MeshSkinVertex`, what we see in print data.

Bmesh also has a some skin data `BMesh.verts.layers.skin`, but it doesn't return any useful data.

Is there any way to access skin data?

Comment: do it in Object mode when using `obj.data.skin_vertices[0].data` directly. Edit Mode will not output anything

Comment: Thanks, its work. Mesh in EDIT mode return skin data and might be modified.

Comment: Why not generate a new mesh with modifiers applied via: bpy.context.object.to_mesh( bpy.context.scene, True, 'RENDER' )?

Answer (score 1):

The original question you link to mentions this in the first line, but doesn't make a point to clarify why the Object/Edit mode switch is important.

#### Non BMesh

When using `obj.data.skin_vertices[0].data`, the *Skin Modifier* data will show the correct current values only when the object is put back in Object Mode. The same is also true for checking other information of the mesh, like `vertex.select`.

#### BMesh

It may be possible to get this skin information while still in Edit Mode using `bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)` but I have not been able to find an obvious way. If it is possible someone will no doubt offer a suggestion.