# Modify skin radius using bmesh

Tags: python, modeling, bmesh

this might be a very basic question. I am trying to modify the skin radius using a bmesh command. The index of the vertex is known. I just wonder what the bmesh command is to access the skin radius and then modify it.

This is similar to this question: [Python access to Skin Modifier data - again](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39197/python-access-to-skin-modifier-data-again)
. However, there is no solution using bmesh module.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python access to Skin Modifier data - again](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39197/python-access-to-skin-modifier-data-again)

Comment: @RayMairlot Thanks but this question does not give solution of using bmesh module. I want to access and modify skin radius using bmesh command instead of bpy module.