# Can Skin Resize values be animated?

Tags: animation, modifiers, shape-keys

With the skin modifier, I can go into edit mode, select a vertex, and hit Ctrl+A or F3 and "Skin Resize" to change its individual radius. This is great for things like manual tree trunks.

However, suppose I'm doing something different that changes with time--like a cartoon garden hose that I want to show water pumping through. (I know this could more easily be done with a curve, but for the sake of example.) I initially suspected that Skin Resize was a property of the vertex, but the shape keys completely ignore it, so it seems that isn't true and it might even be exclusively related to the modifier. I could insert a key frame for it, but I don't have any known field giving me the value.

Can someone shed some light on this mysterious operation, and how it can be accessed from animation or script? The documentation unfortunately hasn't been terribly helpful. I would even settle for a driver trick.

ADDENDUM: So far, I've gotten around this limitation (be it in Blender or my understanding of it) by creating a custom property and adding a lattice; and tying the shape key and the carefully placed and limited lattice to that property with a driver. It's extremely roundabout, though.

Comment: The skin modifier vertex radii are a very peculiar beast. I would suggest you pursue other means to do what you want to do, but if you really want to animate them you're going to have to do it with a script and the python API I'm afraid : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1593/86891

Comment: @Gorgious That's a start, thanks. I honestly feel like it's a great idea that's only halfway implemented.

Comment: I've read that the skin modifier will be completely redesigned at some point for Geometry Nodes. No idea on the ETA though so I wouldn't hold my breath ^^

Comment: @Gorgious The first rule of Blender is to never hold your breath; the second rule is to expect absolutely anything at any time with no warning.